# When did Kay Nishi offer a million dollars for a competing DOS?

Tags: history, ms-dos

The development of Digital Research's fully-compatible MS-DOS competitor, DR DOS, was encouraged when, according to https://retrotechnology.com/dri/dri_wein.html

> After DOS Plus for Philips we did a version for Amstrad, but soon it became apparent that we needed a more native implementation of the DOS API to be more compatible, and the opportunity arose when Kay Nishi of ASCII Corporation in Japan put up a million dollars for a contract to develop it after he fell out with Microsoft (he had been instrumental in opening the Japanese OEM market for Microsoft).

The falling out happened March 14, 1986, according to this paywalled article: https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052748703806304576232724103241208

> The tensions finally came to a head in March, the day after Microsoft completed a very successful public offering.

When did Nishi offer, and subsequently award, the million dollar contract for the DOS competitor?

Comment: Interesting, but shouldn't be the first question if _he did at all?_ Proving would be foundation to find a data and what followed, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn Right, the ideal answer would have references to the specifics of what happened – or, if it turns out there is evidence that this never happened at all, that would also be very interesting!

Comment: You’re writing like there was some sort of contest, but the  quote mentions a contract.  Contracts have requirements and penalties, etc.